# How to use azureml.core.runconfig.DockerConfiguration class in azureml.core.Environment or azureml.core.ScriptRunConfig class

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I use Microsoft Azure Machine Learning (Azure-ml) to run my (python) experiments.

For specifying the VM and python environment I use:

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig

# Other imports and code...

# Specify VM and Python environment:
vm_env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name='my-test-env', file_path=PATH_TO_YAML_FILE)
vm_env.docker.enabled = True
vm_env.docker.base_image = 'mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-cuda10.2-cudnn7-ubuntu18.04'

# Finally, use the environment in the ScriptRunConfig:
src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=DEPLOY_CONTAINER_FOLDER_PATH,
                      script=SCRIPT_FILE_TO_EXECUTE,
                      arguments=EXECUTE_ARGUMENTS,
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      environment=vm_env)
```

I get the following warning for the line `vm_env.docker.enabled = True`:

```
'enabled' is deprecated. Please use the azureml.core.runconfig.DockerConfiguration object with the 'use_docker' param instead.
```

The documentation about the [`DockerSection Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.dockersection?view=azure-ml-py) and [`DockerConfiguration Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.runconfig.dockerconfiguration?view=azure-ml-py) is not very clear about applying the `DockerConfiguration Class`.

**I can't figure out how to use the `azureml.core.runconfig.DockerConfiguration` object. Can someone provide me with an example? Thank you!**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ScriptRunConfig` class now accepts a `docker_runtime_config` argument, which is where you pass the `DockerConfiguration` object.

So, the code would look something like this:

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig
from azureml.core.runconfig import DockerConfiguration

# Other imports and code...

# Specify VM and Python environment:
vm_env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name='my-test-env', file_path=PATH_TO_YAML_FILE)
vm_env.docker.base_image = 'mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-cuda10.2-cudnn7-ubuntu18.04'

docker_config = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)

# Finally, use the environment in the ScriptRunConfig:
src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=DEPLOY_CONTAINER_FOLDER_PATH,
                      script=SCRIPT_FILE_TO_EXECUTE,
                      arguments=EXECUTE_ARGUMENTS,
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      environment=vm_env,
                      docker_runtime_config=docker_config)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this in the next couple of days and let you know how it goes :).

Comment: It works flawlessly. For other people reading this, remember you also have to use `from azureml.core.runconfig import DockerConfiguration`.

Comment: Awesome - glad to hear it!

Answer (score 9):

Adding another example for anyone using RunConfiguration:

Change:

```
run_config = RunConfiguration()
run_config.environment.docker.enabled = True
```

To:

```
run_config = RunConfiguration()
docker_config = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)
run_config.docker = docker_config
```

`run_config` can later be used as a parameter for e.g. PythonScriptStep.

Note that the docker attribute moved from the internal `environment` to the `RunConfiguration` directly.

Comment: Thanks, this was super useful for a problem I' struggling with.

Comment: I works great for me too, a quick and easy fix. Thanks!